# Extract specific value from a big data matrix

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a big matrix in which the first row contains the variable_name and the first column contains the name of the objects (variables and objects are the same, it's comparison all vs all). Moreover, I have 2 different text files. The first (`file1.txt`) contains the object of interest (I should use this file to select the row of interest-based on the name object reported in the first column of the matrix) while the second file (`list.txt`)contains a shorter list of objects and I should use this list to select the relative columns of the matrix that starting with the name of the objects reported in the list. the aim is to use these two txt files to extract the relative scores in the matrix.

e.g. matrix.txt: ( Columns are separated by a tab)

```
Object  3mup_A_001_____ 3oz1_A_001_____ 456r_V_002_____ 23er_B_001_____ 87t5_C_001_____
23er_B_001_____ 0.5     0.3     0.87    1       0.9
456r_V_002_____ 0.2     0.7     0.65    0.63    0.2
87t5_C_001_____ 0.35    0.5     0.254   0.12    1
dret_A_009_____ 0.99    0.88    0.7     0.89    0.214
3mup_A_001_____ 0.12    0.15    0.87    0.17    0.87
```

file1.txt:

```
87t5_C_001_____
```

list.txt:

```
3mup_A_001_____
456r_V_002_____
```

I should use the `file1.txt` (87t5_C_001____) to select the object of interest in the first column (select the 4th row of the matrix) and obtained the score associated at the column (variable) that starting with the name of the objects including in the file `list.txt`.

output.txt

```
Object  3mup_A_001_____ 456r_V_002_____
87t5_C_001_____ 0.35    0.254
```

As an alternative, if it's simpler, the output could have also in another format, for example reporting the score near the object in the list:

```
3mup_A_001_____ 0.35
456r_V_002_____ 0.254
```

I hope that it's clear and that someone could help me because I don't know how I can do this operation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
FILENAME == ARGV[1] {
    rowNames[$1]
    next
}
FILENAME == ARGV[2] {
    colNames[$1]
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    rowNames[$1]
    colNames[$1]
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i in colNames) {
            f[++numCols] = i
        }
    }
}
$1 in rowNames {
    for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", $(f[colNr]), (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1.txt list.txt matrix.txt
Object  3mup_A_001_____ 456r_V_002_____
87t5_C_001_____ 0.35    0.254
```

Comment: The scrip give me this error: script.sh: line 1: '$: command not found
script.sh: line 2: BEGIN: command not found
script.sh: line 3: FILENAME: command not found
script.sh: line 4: rowNames[]: command not found
script.sh: line 5: next: command not found
script.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
script.sh: line 6: `}''

Comment: You'd have to tell me what `script.sh` contained if you'd like me to help debug it but my best guess is you saved the awk script in a file named `script.sh` and then tried to execute it as if it was a shell script instead of passing it to `awk` to interpret. Just run the command exactly as shown in my answer - store the awk script in a file named `tst.awk` and run it as `awk -f tst.awk file1.txt list.txt matrix.txt`.

Comment: Sorry I copied the script to a file .sh. Now I did as you say, but it gives me this error: awk: tst.awk:1: $ cat tst.awk
awk: tst.awk:1:          ^ syntax error

Comment: Again, without seeing what you're trying to execute, I can't do much to help you debug it. Whatever it is you have in that file, it's not the script I show in my answer. Oh, hang on - did you put `$ cat tst.awk` at the top of the file? Don't do that - `$` is my prompt and `cat tst.awk` is the shell command I ran to show you the contents of the file `tst.awk`. The awk script that should be in `tst.awk` starts with the line `BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }`.